# Android project local manually created lib

Tags: android, global

I am not sure I did the right thing. The main reason for my doubts is that I cannot find, in this or other forums, someone who has done a similar thing.

I created an abstract java class in my project. Named it **lib**. I put there several structures and methods used by all other classes in the project.

**It works** for me, but I want to know if there is a more accepted method of gathering all common methods and structures.

**Note**: All methods of course are declared as public static.

**Note II**: I did not know how to get the context within the abstract class, so if needed I had to pass it as argument to the method.

Comment: I get confused, what are you trying to achieve here? Centralizing reusable code in common lib?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I don't need a common lib for ALL projects, Just common lib for one project.

Comment: I think you need to more clearly define what this lib is for. There isn't a single strategy for reusing code, there are hundreds of them. Utility classes can help, using design patterns and good coding principles will help. your question is too generic to give a good answer.

Comment: @Matt Wolfe, I think that without willing you gave me the answer I was looking for. I did not know that what I did was called "Utility class", and after you mentioned it I searched for it. And voila!! A lot of people use it, so I am now more confident I made the right choice.

Comment: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=288

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks to @Matt Wolfe's comment I came to know that what I did is called "Utility class" and it is widely used to share common code in a project.
The general template is:

```js
public abstract class lib {

    public static final int ZERO = 0;
    public static final int ONE = 1;
    public static final int TWO = 2;

    public static void func1(int i) { 
    }

    public static void func2(int i, String s) { 
    }

}
```

and you can use it like this from any other code:

```
...;
lib.func1( lib.ZERO );
lib func2( lib.TWO, "sandwich" );
...;
```

Knowing that makes me confident that what I did is OK.

It would be perfect to find a way to avoid the prefix lib. and just have ECLIPSE, and the compiler, find the right import and recognize the function with just its name, like they do for global libraries.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of abstract classes. Abstract means the class should (but doesn't have to) contain abstract methods. How it works is the abstract class declares certain methods as abstract, and often times will declare and define other methods. There is a concept of "polymorphism" that can be used here in which you are able to call the abstract methods from within that class.. Also keep in mind class names should start with an uppercase letter. Also I would suggest grouping utility classes by some common functionality that they perform.

Comment: Also back to abstract classes..  You can never create instances of them directly you must provide a concrete implementation and instantiate that. There really is no reason to make utility classes abstract (that I can think of), because utility classes are just a "psuedo" class really that have a bunch of functions... You don't instantiate them at all typically, you just call the functions.

Comment: You are probably right regarding the user of abstract classes, I meant to say the are not to be instantiated. I should have made the methods final.   The name lib did not constitute a problem it compiles ok and I got no error nor warnings about it.

Comment: If it is not clear from my previous comment, the code I posted is not just an example, it works and I am using it fine.

Comment: Hi Matt, don't patronize me. I have a B.Sc on Computer engineering with majors in Advanced programming and VLSI. I know what naming conventions are. In this case I don't need to follow them because it is a code for my eyes only. If you want to be helpful, tell me how can I call local utility functions without having to create an utility class, so the invocation does not require the 'lib.' prefix I am using now. In any case, I do appreciate your help so far. Thanks.

Comment: Not trying to patronize you sorry. If you look though at Sun Java SDK , android SDK, and every other java code out there they follow the convention that class names begin with an uppercase (and thus the associated filename is uppercase). While you don't have to it has been so well established that you will have a hard time finding anyone who doesn't do it this way. In java you cannot call a static class function without using the name of the class (unless the class you are calling methods from is within the same file you are working with).

Answer (score 0):

Is this wat you are looking for?

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity extends Activity{

    public static synchronized boolean showAlertBox(Context ctx,final String title,final String message,final String okBtnTxt,final OnClickListener clickListener){

    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox; alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
     this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() { 


        alertbox.setTitle(title);
        alertbox.setMessage(message);
        if(okBtnTxt!=null || clickListener!=null)
          alertbox.setNeutralButton(okBtnTxt,clickListener);
        alertbox.show(); 
             .....

     }
     });

     return true;
    }
 }
```

In the class extending this abstract class you can just call it by using showAlertBox(this);
Other wise use AbstractActivity.showAlertBox(Context);

Comment: No, no, no. You misunderstood me. I am not asking how to  call an AlertDialog. The Alert() was just an example of what I put into my lib. I was asking about the fact that I implemented this local lib, it works fine, but nobody seem to have used such a technique before. and since I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I want to know how are global methods usually handled.

Comment: I edited the original question and deleted the Alert() example, to prevent misunderstandings